# Taking date from textbox after adding some numbers of days and storing old and new date in database

Tags: c#, datetime

I am getting an error of date conversion, please help me. Thank you for all.

```
protected void getdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text);
    DateTime dt3 = dt2.AddDays(9);
    txtlastdate.Text = dt3.ToString();        
}
```

Comment: (txtdate.Texenter code heret ) wrong sentence, right one  txtdate.text

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. First of all, I edited your question to make it more clean. But before that, you didn't even mentioned about what kind of error you get. Your question needs more details. Show us more details about your error. You get `FormatException`? What is the value of `txtdate.Text` and what is the value of your `CurrentCulture`. See? We need _more_ details. As a starter, please read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime.ParseExact and you can manage yyyyMMddHHmmss format to manually;

```
 DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Where this `yyyyMMddHHmmss` format came from exactly? o.O

Comment: he can manage datetime format  as a txtdate.Text value. maybe it is must be ddMMyyyyHHmmss. and he can use anyculture whatever he want.

Comment: Giving answers with "maybe" isn't usually helpful on Stack Overflow. Instead of that, better to ask OP to clarify the question. This will be better for both sides.

Comment: Yes you are right, question owner must be specify its given text and what the result should be/

Answer (score -1):

try to add format 
like in this link from msdn :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

example from link for format

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      String[] formats = { "G", "MM/yyyy", @"MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm",
                           "yyyyMMdd" };
      String[] cultureNames = { "en-US", "fr-FR" };
      DateTime date = new DateTime(2015, 8, 18, 13, 31, 17);
      foreach (var cultureName in cultureNames) {
         var culture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
         CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
         Console.WriteLine(culture.NativeName);
         foreach (var format in formats)
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}: {1}", format,
                              date.ToString(format));
         Console.WriteLine();
      }
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       English (United States)
//          G: 8/18/2015 1:31:17 PM
//          MM/yyyy: 08/2015
//          MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm: 08/18/2015 13:31
//          yyyyMMdd: 20150818
//
//       français (France)
//          G: 18/08/2015 13:31:17
//          MM/yyyy: 08/2015
//          MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm: 08/18/2015 13:31
//          yyyyMMdd: 20150818
```

Comment: Sorry but this is a bad example of a good answer. Link only answers are not "complete" ones because if link will dead in future, the answer will be meaningless. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/158761